# pd.read_sql()ですべて文字列で読むことは可能か

Tags: python, pandas

Pythonで

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as psql
```

のもと、`pd.read_sql()`でdtype=objectの実行（もしくはそれに類する操作）は可能でしょうか。
マニュアル的なページを見たのですが、特に記述がありませんでした。
これはそういう機能は存在しないということでよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: 参考までに、6年ほど前に [Suggestion: a dtype argument for read_sql · Issue #6798 · pandas-dev/pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6798) で議論されています。2020/4/26 時点での結論としては、"contributions to improve type handling in sql reading are certainly welcome" となっています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.read_sql()`ではdtypeの明示的な指定はできないと思います。

`pd.read_sql()`は、SQLAlchemyから受け取ったResultProxyを`DataFrame.from_records()`に渡してDataFrameを構築しているようです。`DataFrame.from_records()`はCythonレベルで自動的に列ごとの型推定/変換を行っており、ユーザがdtypeを指定することはできません。

DataFrameを構築後に`astype()`で変換するか、もしくはSQLAlchemy側で明示的にcastしてから`read_sql()`に渡してはいかがでしょうか。